# ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail

Tags: arcgis-pro, overlapping-features, error-999999, business-analyst

Application: ArcGIS Pro 2.8.3

Tool: Remove Overlap (Multiple) Analysis and Business Analyst

Feature Classes: Both polygon and overlapping

Method: Center Line

Coordinate System: WGS1984 (Both layers and data frame)

Error Message:

> ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact
> Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug,
> and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.

[image]

[image]

I tried changing the coordinate system but when running the Remove Overlap tool, ArcGIS Pro crashes and is tested on multiple machines.

When running the tool with the feature classes which I created. It gives no error.

What might be causing the issue or is there any alternative way to achieve the same results?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. 999999 is a generic failure code, so you need to be extremely specific in your problem statement. Please [Edit] the Question to include the exact version of Pro in use, the exact spatial references involved, and the parameters provided to the geoprocessing tool (if you go into the Results log, you can Copy as Python Snippet).

Comment: From your error message:"The Project method cannot do a datum transformation.".  Ensure the data reference the same coordinate reference system and try again.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear here, but it looks like based on "the project method cannot do a datum transformation" that it is some issue with the projection you are using. You wrote above that the coordinate system is WGS1984 which is a coordinate system, but not a projection.

My suggestion would be to use the Project geoprocessing tool to project both of your layers into a projected coordinate system (use an [Alabama state plane](http://alabamamaps.ua.edu/contemporarymaps/alabama/basemaps/stateplane.pdf) projection or a [UTM projection](https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/mapping-utm-grid-conterminous-48-united-states)). Once both layers are projected the same way, try the tool again.